# Error in -0.01 * height : non-numeric argument to binary operator in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

#I am trying to visualize my data in bar plot, (i just started using R so have trying things out). Similar syntax worked for the previous two graphs, however, for this one I don't have any clue what the issue is!

```
s22 <- list("SUP Bottle"= 517.36, "Bottle Caps"= 10.52, "SUP Cups"= 37.96, "Tin"= 58.4, "SUP Bag"= 792.79, "Food Container"= 71.09, "Cloth"= 20.26, "Polyester bag"= 75.8, "Tetra Pack"= 11.09, "Packaging"= 347.36, "Wood"= 246.68, "Rubber"= 670, "Cardboard"= 470.73, "Iron Rod"= 344.21, "plastic pipe"= 40, "Aluminum"= 64, "lubricant bottle"= 102.17, "shoe"= 470.88)

barplot(s22, main = "Site 2.2", horiz = T, xlab = "Mass (g)", col="#69b3a2", las = 3, cex.axis = 1, las=2, cex.main = 2)
```

upon execution, it shows error

> "Error in -0.01 * height: non-numeric argument to binary operator"

I then tried

```
value <- c (517.36, 10.52, 37.96, 58.4,792.79, 71.09, 20.26, 75.8,11.09, 347.36, 246.68, 670, 470.73, 344.21,   40, 64,102.17, 470.88)
N <- C("SUP Bottle", "Bottle Caps", "SUP Cups","Tin","SUP Bag", "Food Container","Cloth", "Polyester bag", "Tetra Pack","Packaging", "Wood", "Rubber", "Cardboard","Iron Rod", "plastic pipe","Aluminum", "lubricant bottle", "shoe")
names(value) <- N
```

but it gave another error

> Error in C("SUP Bottle", "Bottle Caps", "SUP Cups", "Tin", "SUP Bag",  :
> object not interpretable as a factor"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the list to data frame. And then run your code.

```
s22 <- list("SUP Bottle"= 517.36, "Bottle Caps"= 10.52, "SUP Cups"= 37.96, "Tin"= 58.4, "SUP Bag"= 792.79, "Food Container"= 71.09, "Cloth"= 20.26, "Polyester bag"= 75.8, "Tetra Pack"= 11.09, "Packaging"= 347.36, "Wood"= 246.68, "Rubber"= 670, "Cardboard"= 470.73, "Iron Rod"= 344.21, "plastic pipe"= 40, "Aluminum"= 64, "lubricant bottle"= 102.17, "shoe"= 470.88)

barplot(unlist(s22), main = "Site 2.2", horiz = T, xlab = "Mass (g)", col="#69b3a2", las = 3, cex.axis = 1, las=2, cex.main = 2)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked to a certain extent, need to customize the graph. Thank you so much.